# X has 811 features, but LogisticRegression is expecting 22203 features as input

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have used TfidfVectorizer to transform text data for my LogisticRegression model.

1. Before I use `fit_transform` on the features I took out part of the data (there are 5 sources of data and I take out one of them to see later how my model generalizes).
2. Then I split the features into train and test data
3. Then after the model was trained I used `vectorizer.transform` on the totally unseen data but I get the error above.

   ```
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))

    test_unseen_data = clean_df[clean_df['category']!='other']
    clean_df = clean_df[clean_df['category']=='other']
    X_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(clean_df['lemmatized_sentence'])
    y_labels = clean_df['type']

    # train

    unseen_features = vectorizer.transform(test_unseen_data['lemmatized_sentence'])
    unseen_labels = test_unseen_data['type']

    y_pred = best_log_regr.predict(unseen_features)
    y_decision_func = best_log_regr.predict_proba(unseen_features)
   ```

So the features on which I used `fit_transform` have the following characteristics:

```
<51762x22203 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1016880 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The ones that are totally unseen:

```
<745x811 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 12444 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I have used `fit_transform` and `transform` before but I have never had such an issue before.

Comment: Looks like your vocabulary differs in size. Confirm that you do *not* instantiate a new Vectorizer prior to use it on the unseen data.

Comment: Looks like this was the problem. Thanks.